# Need help parsing JSON in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to send integer data through textfield to the json server and whatever calculated result will be provide server that result i want to display in my label field.
How is it possible? Pls, provide me any code how will i send integer data to the server ? And how will i parse that result by use of json parsing ? And how will I display that result in my label  field?

Comment: You should really look up some resources. 

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/
http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/first-json-iphone-application/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to convert int into string first. You can convert int into string as `NSSting *str = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%d",yourint];`

okay than These are the links which can be helpful to you.

[tutorial](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c)

[same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813215/json-framework-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Mam, actually i am new in json parsing and i don't know how to send any data to the json server by use of text field.so pls provide any code for sending input to the server.

Comment: Of course, currentSummary = [currentSummary 
        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@","]; but here i will suggest you to change the data in webservice side rather than from your side.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [JSON Framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)?

Comment: Dear sir, actually i am new in json parsing and i don't know how to send any data to the json server by use of text field.so pls provide  any code for sending input to the server.

Comment: @user853648 - Sorry, I didn't realise. I am unable to get you any code at the moment as I am currently away from home and I can't test it in Xcode. I will update this post later with example code.

Comment: Thanks sir, i will wait for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://www.xprogress.com/post-44-how-to-parse-json-files-on-iphone-in-objective-c-into-nsarray-and-nsdictionary/) is the tutorial to help you out..

To replace space with "," (comma character), following code will do.

```
    NSString *targetString = @"1000 USD= 44 986.6"; 
    NSString *str = [targetString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@","];
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Please check the modified code with the answer of your latest query.